# JS Regex Crashing

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, gruntjs

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction with this. I'm making a little Grunt task that requires some CSS be split up using regex.

Here is an example of the regex in question working as expected:

https://regex101.com/r/gY6zO7/1

For some reason however, when I run this as part of my grunt task it crashes terminal.

```
var regexString = new RegExp("^((?:\.|#)(?:[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|\s|\.|#|-|:|&|,)+?{(?:\s|\n)*(?:\/\*export\*\/)(?:.|\n)*?})", "gm");
var splitString = css.split(regexString);
```

I've tried countless variations but I can't seem to figure out what exactly is going on, any help appreciated!

Comment: \s \n need escaping to \\s \\n

Comment: That's all it was, thanks @AlexK. !!! Add it as an answer and I'll mark it :)

Comment: But, not escaping \s or \n won't cause a crash. Your regex reduces to `^([.#][a-zA-Z0-9\s.#:&,-]+?\{\s*/\*export\*/[\S\s]*?\})` and double quoted  `"^([.#][a-zA-Z0-9\\s.#:&,-]+?\\{\\s*/\\*export\\*/[\\S\\s]*?\\})"`

Comment: Odd @sln - I know the regex is horrendous and needs fixing.. but I just made this change and ran it and it has stopped crashing.. *shrug* - Thanks for the help reducing it down though, saves me some time now :)

Comment: Really? What was the crash error?

Comment: It was just locking up my terminal when I ran the grunt task.. :S

Comment: That's not a crash, that is catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @Mariano - it's passed as a string because the actual code is a little more complicated - it has some variables fed into it.. I just simplified it for the question :)

Comment: @sln - catastrophic backtracking that was fixed by escaping a couple of characters correctly apparently? lol

Comment: Catastrophic backtracking is a symptom the regex quantifiers are wrong. It's not fixed with a change of a literal. It occurs because there is a non-match causing it to retry. If it ever runs into a situation where the literals are not present in the source, it will happen again.

Comment: I see, thanks I'll rework it all now - I just wanted to see something working to be honest :D

Comment: `\s` was interpreted as a literal `s`, which is included in `[a-z]` (included twice under the same quantifier). So for every `s` in your subject there is an exponential number of backtracking states.

Comment: That makes sense and explains what could have been happening - thanks @Mariano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the backslashed `\s` and `\n` to `\\s` and `\\n` as they are inside a string (or use the unquoted `//` syntax).

Comment: Thanks again, I can look at optimising it now :)